# What is the appropriate time series db to Export Azure metrics locally

Tags: azure, prometheus, metrics, monitor

My requirement is to replicate Azure monitor metrics data in local db. I have to show analytics and graphs based on the aggregate and calculations. 
My initial thought was to go for Prometheus db. Please suggest your opinions.
I need last 90 days of data at given point. 
There are 2 stages to bring that data.
Last 90 days metrics data and
Syncing daily metrics data